# How to apply an integrated constrain condition in FEM?

Tags: finite-element, pde, numerical-analysis, boundary-conditions, constrained-optimization

I'm running some simulation using FEM. In my model I need to apply a constraint condition to the governing equation.  My governing equation similar to the diffusion equation as below:

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=\nabla(D\nabla c)\quad\text{on}\quad\Omega$$

and the flux is defined as follow:

$$-D\nabla c\cdot n=J$$

And the constraint condition is an integral. For short, I need to constrain the total flux alone the specific surface equals to a constant, which means:

$$\int_{\partial\Omega_{1}}(-D\nabla c\cdot n)d\Gamma=\text{Constant}$$
where $$\partial\Omega_{1}$$ is part of my domain's surface, not the total surface.

I can write out the weak form for the governing equation(based on N-R method) as follow:
$$R_{c}^{I}=\int_{\Omega}\dot{c}N^{I}d\Omega+\int_{\Omega}D\nabla c\nabla N^{I}d\Omega-\int_{\partial\Omega}D\nabla c\cdot n N^{I}d\Gamma$$
and the related stiffness matrix:
$$K_{c\dot{c}}^{IJ}=-\frac{\partial R_{c}^{I}}{\partial\dot{c}^{J}}=-\int_{\Omega}N^{J}N^{I}d\Omega$$
$$K_{cc}^{IJ}=-\frac{\partial R_{c}^{I}}{\partial c^{J}}=-\int_{\Omega}D\nabla N^{J}\nabla N^{I}d\Omega+\int_{\partial\Omega_{1}}D\nabla N\cdot n N^{I}d\Omega$$

How can I apply $$\int_{\partial\Omega_{1}}(-D\nabla c\cdot n)d\Gamma=\text{Constant}$$ to my FEM system?

Someone told me that Lagrange multiplier can solve this problem, but I still don't know how to do it. I'm a newbie of FEM, so any details are helpful for me.

Comment: See https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/ans_thry/thy_geo6.html

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee: Hi Biswajit, thank you so much for the reply. I see the webpage you give me. Just one question, if I want to constraint all the node's grad(c)*n=Constant, then the formula list on that page is ok, but what I want is the total (or  the integrated ) flux equals to a constant. So will the formula still correct to use? Sorry for my poor FEM knowledge.

Comment: Think of the integral as a sum over nodal quantities (you can use some sort of quadrature to compute that sum), e.g. $\sum_n J_i - C = 0$.  Then the minimization problem will have the extra regularization term $\lambda (\sum_n J_i - C)$ instead of terms for each node, e.g., $\lambda_i (J_i - C)$ .  You can then use the standard process.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, see e.g. [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26967/solving-poisson-equation-with-current-bc-using-fem).

Comment: I wrote a simple Python example for you, see it [here](https://github.com/kinnala/scikit-fem/blob/master/examples/ex5.py). Lines 19 and 24 are about augmenting the system with a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee: thank you Biswajit, I understand what you mentioned here. So the residual of $\lambda$ will be $R_{\lambda}=\int_{\partial\Omega}(\sum_{i}J_{i}-C)N^{I}d\Gamma$, and the $\delta\Phi$ part becomes $\int_{\partial\Omega}\delta(\sum_{i}J_{i}-C) \lambda d\Gamma$, right?

Comment: @knl: hi knl, thank you so much for the reply and you code. Now I'm much closer to the final answer. Actually, I just don't know how the write out the Residual and K matrix. Follow your and biswajit's suggestion, I can write out the residual as wrote below, but still confused about the K matrix part, where I need to do $\frac{\partial R_{\lambda}}{\partial c}$. I need some time to digest it. Thank you!

Comment: @knl: Hi knl, thank you so much. I looked the code, so $A=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\nabla v dV$,$B=-\int_{\partial\Omega}\nabla u*n v dS$,$b=-\int_{\partial\Omega}\nabla v*n dS$. And the final stiffness matrix K is [[A+B,$b^{T}$],[b,0]]. Right?

Comment: Did you read the other question suggested by @knl?